# Equivalent to total variation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Prove that if $X$ is a compact metric space, $B$ is a borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ is a complex measure on $(X,B)$, then the total variation of $\mu$ equals 
$$\sup_{f\in C(X)}\left| \int f d\mu\right|$$ where total variation of $\mu$ is defined as $d|\mu| = |f|\,d\rho$ if $d\mu = f\,d\rho$, where $\rho$ is a positive measure.

This is exercise 7.11 in bass http://bass.math.uconn.edu/3rd.pdf.  Any hints or solutions would be appreciated. The norm on $C(X)$ is the sup norm, I believe.

Comment: whether we can use radon-nikodym theorem here?

Comment: I think you transcribed the problem incorrectly, the $\sup$ above is infinite.

Comment: @copper.hat but, the space $X$ is compact, isnt it?

Comment: I presume you need $\|f\| \le 1$.

Comment: I think it's restricted to continuous functions with finite sup.  Does that resolve the issue?

Comment: I don't think so, if $\int f d \mu \neq 0$ then by choosing $c$ you can make $c \int f d\mu$ as large as you want, so you need some restrictions.